# Logstash grok filter - field value duplicated

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My *logstash* filter is configured as follows:

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/patterns/"]
    match => {
      "[message]" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{THREAD:thread} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{LOGGER:logger} %{CONTEXT:context} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    }
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { "[fields][index]" => "application" }
    rename => { "[host][name]" => "instance" }
    remove_field => ["@version","agent.ephemeral_id","agent","ecs","fields","input","tags"]
  }
}
```

Grok debugger suggests everything is fine, and for error line:

```
2020-10-28 05:14:41,282 [Worker-5] DEBUG Amount  - calculate operation: [1], useCurrencyCodeOfPosition: [false]
```

I am getting the below output:

```
{
  "level": "DEBUG",
  "logger": "Amount",
  "context": "",
  "thread": "Worker-5",
  "message": "calculate operation: [1], useCurrencyCodeOfPosition: [false]",
  "timestamp": "2020-10-28 05:14:41,282"
}
```

Patterns are defined as follows:

```
THREAD \[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\]
LOGGER (?<logger>[^ ]*)
CONTEXT (?<context>[^-]*)
```

Now, each value produced by grok filter is duplicated as the below example shows:

```
             "logger" => [
    [0] "Amount",
    [1] "Amount"
],
             "thread" => [
    [0] "[Worker-5]",
    [1] "Worker-5"
```

What's the issue here?
I just cannot figure it out.
It's my first filter :).
I'm working with Logstash *7.9.2* (dockerized)

Comment: This must have sth to do with my custom patterns... just do not know what yet :/

Comment: "In-lining" the patterns work as expected, but it's not the preferred way I'd think :/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are problems with the custom patterns in the filter. What you want can also be achieved simply using out of the box patterns like below

```
filter{
 grok {
    match => {
      "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:logger} %{DATA:context}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    }
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { "[fields][index]" => "application" }
    rename => { "[host][name]" => "instance" }
    remove_field => ["@version","agent.ephemeral_id","agent","ecs","fields","input","tags"]
  }
}
```

Checkout [this](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) link of default grok patterns. If you need to do time-series analysis on these events, I would suggest you to override `@timestamp` with `timestamp` or at-least apply date filter on `timestamp`.

If you are expecting to capture multi-line stack trace errors, consider using multi-line filter on the input plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this. What's wrong with my patterns thou? I must be missing something.

Comment: @ m0rt1m3r The regex being used for custom patterns do not match the required patterns in your log.  Please upvote - accept the answer if it resolves your query :).

Comment: I disagree. In the output you can clearly see that values are being extracted, aka regexes are ok. I just don't understand why my custom patterns do not work (they find values but values are duplicated). I am doing sth wrong there.

Comment: Ohh yes now I see.your patterns are actually responsible for multiple matches. Try them in standalone on regex101.

Comment: Yup, as mentioned earlier. In-lining regex-es work fine. I just want to understand what am I doing wrong with custom patterns. :)